# Dimension of $End(V)$ with $V$ countable dimension irreducible module over a complex algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, cardinals, division-algebras

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and $V$ be an irreducible $A$-module with countable dimension. What is the dimension of $End(V)$ as $A$-module? Note that every endomorphism must be injective and surjective, because of the irreducibility of $V$. My claim (or at least my hope) is that $End(V)$ has countable dimension, but I can't see a proof of this fact.

Comment: I made some mistakes I've just edited; however I mean irreducible module, that is a module with no bilateral submodules except himself and $(0)$.

Comment: It is much clearer now, thanks for the edits.

Comment: Without loss of generality you can assume $V$ is a faithful $A$ module and think about right primitive rings and apply the Jacobson density theorem.

Comment: Can you please explain the proof with more details in an answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: Every $R$ module $M$ is a faithful $R/Ann(M)$ module: it’s a good exercise.

Comment: Ok, but even assuming that I can't see the way to conclude.

Comment: I didn’t say that it gives you your answer, I just meant you could reduce the problem to something with a good structure theorem.

Comment: What is “dimension” “as $A$-module”? Also, what is “countable” - infinite or not necessarily?

Comment: A good question @Dap. When composing my answer I assumed "countably infinite" for some reason :-). Deleting the misguided answer.

Comment: Well, for countable finite my claim is true and the proof is not difficult; for infinite I'm in trouble. Dimension is the largest cardinality of a set of linearly indipendent elements over A.

Comment: How is $End(V)$ an $A$-module?

Comment: What does it mean by $\operatorname{End}V$?  Is it $\operatorname{End}_\Bbb{C}V$ or is it $\operatorname{End}_AV$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to interpret the question as asking about dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ , as it is not clear what $A$-module structure $End_A(V)$ has.

If $V$ is a left $A$-module which is irreducible in the sense that it has no proper nontrivial left $A$-modules, then $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} End_A(V) \leq \dim_{\mathbb C} V$. For if $v \in V \setminus \{0\}$, then $V = Av$, and thus the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map
\begin{align*} End_A(V) &\to V  \\ \varphi &\mapsto \varphi(v) \end{align*}
is injective.

Schur's Lemma tells us that every nonzero endomorphism in $End_A(V)$ is in fact invertible, that is, that $End_A(V)$ is a division algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ of countable dimension. While it is well known that the only finite-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}$ itself, the same result is true of division algebras $D$ of countable dimension, as can be seen by examining for $a \in D \setminus \mathbb{C}$ the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: a - z \text{ is not invertible}\}$.